# What does "なかなか" mean here?

Tags: translation

This was dialogue from a detective manga where a police officer is interrogating a suspect.

> 脅迫気味に二人切になれた

*(I got intimated with just the of us alone (?))*

> もののなかなか口を割らないので
>
> ゴリ押し...

*(I'll force through this)*

I did find this [https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/口を割らない](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8F%A3%E3%82%92%E5%89%B2%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) so I assume it means to "keep one mouth's shut" Is that correct?

But my main issue here is I don't know what もののなかなか means here. Is it an adjective here? There's also a lot of different meanings for it so I'm confused.

Japandict says it means "by no means, not readily" when using with a negative verb. Though in that case, I'm not sure what the function of "ものの" is.

Is it "They won't reveal the truth by any means"?

Comment: Related (regarding ものの): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13351/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61268/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ものの is a conjunction meaning "although". It's like (の)だが, けれども.

- [JGram: ものの](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=monono)
- [JLTP Sensei: ものの](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE-mono-no/)

And なかなか is a [negative polarity](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010) adverb meaning "(not) easily" or "(not) readily". 口を割る means "to confess (e.g., to a crime)" or "to cop out". There is no adjective in your sentence.